# For each and if loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a loop which tests each cell in for the number 1, when one is present I want to store the value in the adjacent cell (column A) and transpose all of these in a separate sheet.

However, VBA is not one of my strong points and I'm struggling with getting the first part to work, my code:

```
Sub test_loop()

Dim Needed_range As Long
Needed_range = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range(Needed_range)
        If cell = 1 Then
           MsgBox "Yes"
           Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Sorry if this is really basic, I don't use VBA often and am going to need to take a refresher to finish this project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to use a `For Each` loop, but you need to construct a `Range` object to loop through first.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_loop()
    Dim neededRange As Range, cell As Range

    'get the range to loop through
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set neededRange = Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cell In neededRange
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
           cell.Offset(0,-1).Value = cell.Value 'put 1 into column A
           'do something else
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

- Try not to underscores in variable names. Underscores have a specific meaning elsewhere in VBA
- Don't forget to declare all variables -- I declared `cell` for you. If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, you'll be reminded by the IDE
- Rather than just `Range("A1")` try to *fully qualify* your ranges. I.e. `Workbooks("..").Worksheets("..").Range("A1")`. I've done this above in the `With` statement

Comment: `cell.Offset(-1,0)` is one row above, not one column to the left, it need to be `cell.Offset(0, -1)`

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Loop Column B and return Yes with row number, then save value of Column B to Column A

```
Sub test_loop()

Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        If Cells(i, "B").Value = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Yes! Appears at row " & i
            Cells(i,"A").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the worksheet object, such as `Value = ..something` takes the longest for the code to process.

You can avoid that, by using a "helper" range, in the code below I'm using `CopyValRng`, and every time the cell in column B equals 1 (`cell.Value = 1`), I'm adding the cell on the left (column A) to that range, using `Application.Union`.

At the end, I'm just changing the values in the entire range at once using `CopyValRng.Value = 1`.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_loop()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Needed_range As Range, cell As Range, CopyValRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

' set the worksheet object, modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
With Sht
    ' get last row in column B
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' set the range
    Set Needed_range = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

    ' loop through the Range
    For Each cell In Needed_range
        If cell.Value = 1 Then
            If Not CopyValRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyValRng = Application.Union(CopyValRng, cell.Offset(0, -1))
            Else
                Set CopyValRng = cell.Offset(0, -1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell    
End With

' make sure there's at least 1 cell in the range, then put 1's in all the cells in column A at once
If Not CopyValRng Is Nothing Then CopyValRng.Value = 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

(neededRange doesn't stock a range but just the last non empty row in column B)
try this code :

```
    Sub test_loop()

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = 1 Then
            Cells(i, 2).Select
               MsgBox "Yes"
               Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you add `Cells(i,2).Select`?

Comment: It was just for me to check if it select the right cell .. you can remove this line ..

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!